# error: invalid conversion from char to const char*

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I am getting the titular error in the following code.

`rna_transcription_test.cpp`

```
#include "rna_transcription.h"
#define BOOST_TEST_MAIN
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(transcribes_cytidine_to_guanosine)
{
    BOOST_REQUIRE_EQUAL('G', transcription::to_rna('C'));
}

#if defined(EXERCISM_RUN_ALL_TESTS)
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(transcribes_guanosine_to_cytidine)
{
BOOST_REQUIRE_EQUAL('C', transcription::to_rna('G'));
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(transcribes_adenosine_to_uracil)
{
    BOOST_REQUIRE_EQUAL('U', transcription::to_rna('A'));
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(transcribes_thymidine_to_adenosine)
{
    BOOST_REQUIRE_EQUAL('A', transcription::to_rna('T'));
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(transcribes_all_dna_nucleotides_to_their_rna_complements)
{
    BOOST_REQUIRE_EQUAL("UGCACCAGAAUU", transcription::to_rna("ACGTGGTCTTAA"));
}
#endif
```

`rna_transcription.h`

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class transcription
{
    public:
        static string to_rna(string input)
        {
            string returnValue;
            for(char& c:input)
            {
                if(c == 'A')
                {
                    returnValue.push_back('U');
                }
                else if(c == 'T')
                {
                    returnValue.push_back('A');
                }
                else if(c == 'G')
                {
                    returnValue.push_back('C');
                }
                else if(c == 'C')
                {
                    returnValue.push_back('G');
                }
            }
            return returnValue;
      };
};
```

I know I just posted this, but I have a feeling that the error is in rna_transcription_test.cpp because I got rna_transcription.h checked by stackoverflow and they said it was bug free. So can someone bugcheck both files, and make sure I got everything right?

Comment: If you posted the error instead of paraphrasing it, we would know more. You know it names the exact place?

Comment: The question is not overly long, and it is complete.  But do try and get in the habit as early as possible of embracing the "Minimal" in "Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example".  That means deleting as much of your code as you can while still demonstrating the problem.  As your problem can be seen even if EXERCISM_RUN_ALL_TESTS is not defined, then all that code could have been omitted.  The specifics of `to_rna` were also not important; it could have just returned its input string and you'd still have the problem.  Minimize!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::string` does NOT have a `char` constructor. If you want to build a string from a single `char` you'd have to say `std::string(1, 'A')`

It does not have a char constructor because `char` is an integer and integer arguments would auto-convert to characters, resulting in very strange bugs.

So change your calls from `transcription::to_rna('A')` to `transcription::to_rna("A")`

Also change your test comparisons to strings instead of characters.

Update:

According to legalize, the tests are perfect as they are. So the answer is not to change the tests but to change your code.

You will need to add another to_rna overload function that receives a single char. You would probably want to update your code so that your loop over the string calls the single char function for each character. That would reduce the duplication from writing the if/then series twice.

Comment: It's still not working after I change the calls. Same errors again.

Comment: @twerk_it_606 Did you change the compared character too, e.g. *BOOST_REQUIRE_EQUAL(**"G"**, transcription::to_rna(**"C"**));* ?

Comment: This actually isn't the problem at all :)